# JDBC determine active transaction

Tags: java, jdbc

Is it a way to determine with JDBC that I'm in not committed active transaction?
I want to be sure that all transaction are committed or rollbacked before Connection.close().

Comment: Similar but not identical question, maybe or not it helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299694/oracle-how-to-find-out-if-there-is-a-transaction-pending

Comment: How would you have an active transaction on a connection that you created and use with your code? Are you sharing the connection between threads?

Comment: It is needed for tests. To check that transaction is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard JDBC method to do what you want. But if you want to make sure all transactions are committed / rollbacked before Connection.close(), you can do this:

```
Connection conn = null;

try {
    conn = ...;
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    // do stuff

    // commit only if everything is successful
    conn.commit();
}
catch (SomeException e) {
    // log exceptions
}
finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        /* ALWAYS rollback before closing the connection
         * if there's any caught/uncaught exception, the transaction will be rolled back
         * if everything is successful / commit is successful, the rollback will have no effect
         */
        try {
            conn.rollback();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {}

        try {
            conn.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {}
    }
}
```

This is better than rolling back only if there's an Exception (in the catch block) because, if there's any uncaught exception:

- rollback() will not be called
- Connection.close() will be called while there's an active transaction, and what happens to the active transaction is implementation-specific. See [Bogdan Calmac's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562609/behaviour-of-active-transaction-on-connection-close).

Comment: "There's no standard JDBC method to do what you want." - It's the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look into [`V$TRANSACTION`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/dynviews_2149.htm) view provided by Oracle.

```
SELECT
   s.osuser, vp.spid as os_pid, S.BLOCKING_SESSION blocker,
   S.SID, S.SERIAL#, S.USERNAME, S.MACHINE,
   Q.SQL_FULLTEXT cur_sql, PQ.SQL_FULLTEXT prev_sql, 
   vt.used_urec, vt.start_date
FROM 
   v$session S
   LEFT JOIN v$sqlarea Q on S.SQL_ID = Q.SQL_ID
   LEFT JOIN v$sqlarea PQ on S.PREV_SQL_ID = PQ.SQL_ID
   LEFT JOIN v$process vp on s.paddr = vp.addr
   LEFT JOIN v$transaction vt on s.saddr = vt.ses_addr
WHERE
   vt.start_date < SYSDATE - (5/1440)
--   AND
--   s.machine = 'machine.name'
ORDER BY 
   S.SID
;
```

Source of query: [What I Learned Today](http://blog.takechances.net/2008/05/oracle-open-transactions.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I want to find the DBMS-independent way.